# Python map lambda filter help using IF

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, reduce

> Given a list of N numbers, use a single list comprehension to produce a new list that only contains those values that are:
>
> (a) even numbers, and
> (b) from elements in the original list that had even indices

I am looking for a solution to the above problem. As suggested [here](http://www.toptal.com/python/interview-questions) there is an easy way to solve it but I would like to know if there is a way I can use a combination of map, lambda and filter on the "FULL" input list.

I am trying to do something like this but it doesn't work.

```
>>> map(lambda i,x : x%2==0 or (i+1)%2==0, range(0,len(l)-1),l)
[False, True, False, True, True]
```

Ideally I need to write something like (added "x if") but that doesnt work. Any suggestions?

```
map(lambda i,x : ***x if*** x%2==0 or (i+1)%2==0, range(0,len(l)-1),l)
```

Comment: Why do you want to solve it this way? map and filter aren't exactly deprecated, but a list comprehension is the logical solution here.

Comment: I am just trying to learn these features and want to know if there is a way to use IF with map and get a list of values back instead of a list of booleans... Do you know if there is a way?

Comment: Afaik, map doesn't allow if. You probably can use lambda with a conditional expression: a = b if c else d; that should solve the booleans problem.

Comment: You are filtering based on some criteria. `map` will not help you on this. It does not filter the input. It just applies a function to each element in the list.

Comment: Do the values have to satisfy both conditions _a_ and _b_, or just at least one of them?

Answer (score 2):

The problem specifically says "use a single list comprehension".

That having been said, you could do something like this:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[0] % 2 == 0 and x[1] % 2 == 0, enumerate([0, 1, 5, 4, 4])))
```

`enumerate` will zip the indices with the digits themselves producing [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 4)]

`filter` with the given lambda will only be satisfied if both numbers in the tuple are even

`map` with the given lambda will discard the indices and keep the original numbers

leaving you with [0, 4] for this example